# Simple background changing CSS animation dosent work

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a little animation that change the background image of a **div**, but is only working with google chrome (no safari and no edge).
I  really dont know why please help.

```
@keyframes backAnimM1
{

0%
{
    background-image: url(../medias/portada/1.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

45%
{
     background-image: url(../medias/portada/2.jpg);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
}
50%
{
    background-image: url(../medias/portada/3.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
75%
{
    background-image: url../medias/portada/4.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
80%
{
    background-image: url(../medias/portada/5.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
100%
{
    background-image: url(../medias/portada/1.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
}
```

And this:

```
#backAnimationMod1
{
animation: backAnimM1 10s infinite;
-webkit-animation:backAnimM1 10s infinite;
-moz-animation:backAnimM1 10s infinite;
-o-animation:backAnimM1 10s infinite;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: At 75% you are missing an opening parenthesis --> ( ... that might break the animation, irrespective of anything else that may be occurring

Comment: true I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include a prefix for your keyframes for webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera):

```
@-webkit-keyframes backAnimM1
{...
```

Basically, keep what you have, and then make a copy of it for webkit browsers with the webkit- prefix.

Comment: Yes I did it but nothing changes, maybe there is a prefix for IE and Edge

Comment: Interesting. IE should work without a prefix. The others you need to prefix.

Comment: I think the probleme is background-image: url(../medias/portada/5.jpg);

Comment: Is posible to change an image without these?

Comment: Yes, using Javascript.

Comment: If you want to stay with CSS, but have a small library handle all the prefixes for you, check out animate.css. It is very easy to implement. You just import the CSS and add the appropriate class to each element you want to animate. It includes fade-in and fade-out functionality and easing.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, its look like ***background-image*** in animation is not suported.

```
    <div class="bg" id="item_1"></div>
<div class="bg" id="item_2"></div>
<div class="bg" id="item_3"></div>
<div class="bg" id="item_4"></div>


<style>




.bg{
position: absolute;
width:1000px;
height:200px;;
background-repeat: 'no-repeat';
background-position: 'center';
background-size: cover;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes backAnim1
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    23%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25%
    {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    26%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    98%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    99%
    {
        opacity: 0,5;
    }
    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }

}

@-webkit-keyframes backAnim2
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    24%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    48%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    49%
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    50%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes backAnim3
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    48%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49%
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    50%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    73%
    {
         opacity: 1;
    }
    74%
    {
         opacity: 0.5;
    }
     75%
    {
         opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes backAnim4
{
    0%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    73%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    74%
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    75%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    97%
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    98%
    {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    99%
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

#item_1
{
opacity: 0.0;
 background-image: url(medias/portada/1.jpg);
 -webkit-animation: backAnim1 18s infinite;
}

#item_2
{
opacity: 0.0;
 background-image: url(medias/portada/2.jpg);
 -webkit-animation: backAnim2 18s infinite;
}

#item_3
{
opacity: 0.0;
 background-image: url(medias/portada/3.jpg);
 -webkit-animation: backAnim3 18s infinite;
}

#item_4
{
opacity: 0.0;
 background-image: url(medias/portada/4.jpg);
 -webkit-animation: backAnim4 18s infinite;
}
</style>
```